# .NET Garbagecollector trouble. Blocks for 15-40 mins

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, garbage-collection

Some facts:
We have developed wcf service that acts as a layer between clients and the database.
It's selfhosted and runs as a windows service.

The service keeps several caches, where the largest are about 1-2gb in memory. Total memory usage is usually about 5-8gb.
Connections are duplex and uses tcp protocol and the serialization is made with protobuf-net. Our connected client count usually range from 1000-1500.
The server is a 8-core xeon of newish model with 64gb memory and runs nothing more then the service.

The problem: After x amount of time, it has been everywhere from a day to a week the service gets extremely slow. Requests that takes 0.5 seconds can take over a minute. This behaviour goes on for 15-40 minutes or til the service is restarted.

What we have done :
We have checked the network and network connection to the server and there is no problem. CPU utilization goes up somewhat during this time from f.eks. 30% avg to 40-50% avg. 
We have taken memory dumps and there are no logical locks in code that blocks the users and not much activity at all. 
Our latest lead is the Garbage collector. In perfmon we can see that  "% time in gc" is constantly over 90%,(90-97%) and the collection counts rises. Both GC0 and GC1. We suspect there is a blocking GC2 running also but we had to restart the service as this is in production so it didn't count up during the 5min window we ran perfmon. Memory usage was 7,6 Gb.
Note : Calls outstanding rises so the calls get there but the service does not handle them.

My questions are, Can the garbage collector get in a state where it runs and blocks constantly for over 15minutes? or are the problem probably related to some other issue?

Our service ran GC in workstation mode and latencymode : Interactive 
We have now changed this to Server and SustainedLowLatency and hopes this will help somewhat. Are there anything else we can do if its the garbage collector?

Edit : The large memory usage is by design, the data in the caches is that large and there is lots of more memory available.

Comment: Suggest to find out the root cause of high usage of memory...e.g. try adding "using" block to free memory once finished using that object

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how many threads do you have? Check in the Task Manager. At least some years ago there was a problem that the more threads you had (even idle), the slower the GC

Comment: "Can the garbage collector get in a state where it runs and blocks constantly for over 15minutes"? Absolutely, if it constantly needs to free up memory but is unable to because you keep holding on to it. As Raymond Chen put it, "a cache with a bad policy is another name for a memory leak".

Comment: The high memory usage is intended, the data we cache is that large and we want it to be cached. I don't think we can have 1500 clients generating sql queries as that would kill overall performance.
The memory usage isnt growing over time but is more or less constant per day. 5gb one day, and 7gb another day depending on the daily usage. The data in the cache is released after 4hours of inactivity(on item level) so it builds up during the day and released at night.
There are atleast 50Gb free memory on the machine.

Comment: Exactly how are you caching this? Are you using the MemoryCache object? Some other library? Something built in-house?

Comment: A big cache that churns can cause large object heap fragmentation that can prevent the garbage collector from working effectively. If you have .NET 4.5.1 or later, you can see if using [LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode) helps. If you are still on .NET 4.0, you definitely want to move to at least 4.5, as it has improved LOH allocation. All this is assuming the LOH is indeed your issue; diagnosing memory issues in general is a broad topic not well suited to an answer.

Comment: The cache is created inhouse. If its the LOH that gets fragmented, which seems possible as we usually dont run into trouble the first couple of days even if the memory usage is the same. I guess it would help to dispose the caches during low usage hours and create new ones.

Answer (score 4):

Excessive garbage collection is often caused by code issues. You either create too many objects in a short time, or you keep allocating memory without releasing it.

There is actually an [extensive checklist available on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851764%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#performance_check_procedures) that should help you diagnose the problem.

A very large GC2 means that the objects in there survived multiple garbage collections, which means they are kept in memory for a longer period of time. That could be the root cause of your issue. Maybe there is a caching mechanism that could use some tuning / retention policy (remove data that isn't used for a long time).

Comment: Our largest cache is more or less a immutable collection, it adds data when asked for and its missing. The item then has 4 hour ttl if its not accessed again then the counter is reset. So its quite simple.
A common scenario is that it grows to 1-1,5gb early in the day. then adds 0.5gb new data and removes 0,5gb and at night it's totally cleared.
If its the cache that is the problem i would like to be able to tell the gc to dont touch it at all during daytime and scan it at night.
Will i get this behaviour if i set Sustainedlowlatency and then force a gc.collect at night?

Comment: Johan: if you set it the GC will still come more frequent than once a day. GC is a continues process. Note the remarks section on [`GCLatencyMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gclatencymode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "Full blocking collections may still occur if the system is under memory pressure."

Comment: If i would like to have a large persistant cache in .net.
How would i then implement it in a way that the GC wont ruin my performance? I want to tell it when to check?
CLR hosting with retain or something?

Comment: @JohanLindberg: Sorry, too advanced for me. If you ask a new question regarding this, you will have my vote, and even a bounty to attract a good answer. It is something I'd like to have too for one of my projects. Please refer to this question and show the general idea, just like you did now.

Comment: If someone is interested, This blogpost by coderguru Marc Gravell seems to address the same problem. http://blog.marcgravell.com/2011/10/assault-by-gc.html

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation.   Large database data cache in a service using protobuf with WCF for client communication.  The cache is not purely just for clients, the business layer uses the cache to perform operations.  The memory footprint of the service can be anywhere between 2 and 10 GB.  I release a segment of the cache after 8 hours of inactivity.  The machine has 8 virtual cores and 32 GB of memory.  I am using .Net 4.5.1.

The GC would consume 98% of the CPU for an hour as soon as I loaded the cache from the database.   The interesting point here in both our cases there is no memory pressure what so ever.

I think the GC is performed regardless because something was changed where the GC tries to keep available memory for all threads.  Since one thread allocated a large amount of memory when loading the cache, the GC kicked in.   I had to do several things to fix it.

1) Removed Tuples from the cache.   I was using them as dictionary keys and their implementation of StructuralEquality is horrible.  It compares all properties as objects so there is a lot of boxing going on for properties that are values and these will have to be garbage collected at some point.

2) When replacing Tuples used as keys I could not simply replace them with structures without implementing Equals as the value comparison uses reflection and it is too expensive so I ended up creating a Generic Pair structure.  I decided to use structures to remove the number of objects when they were in arrays.

3) To remove the Tuples I had to create my own Pair structure that compares the properties using default equals for property types.  Eseentially the same thing that PowerCollections created.