# How to create a large(10gb+) persistent cache in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, caching, garbage-collection

Spin-off from my other question.
[.NET Garbagecollector trouble. Blocks for 15-40 mins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850042/net-garbagecollector-trouble-blocks-for-15-40-mins)

I want to create a simple persistent cache. For simplicity, everything that goes in stays in. I have currently implemented this with a `ImmutableDictionary<int,DataItem>` but I have problem with the garbage collector.

It seems to think I use lots of data which is true it as it contains 10 000-100 000 complex objects, and then it begins to think its a good idea to scan the cache very often. With blocking Generation 2. At least that's what I believe it does. "%Time in gc" is 90%+ and my application is blazing slow.

Can I somehow mark the cache as untouchable or let my app use more memory before GC thinks it should do a full collect? I have loads of free memory on the server.

Might switching to NCache or Redis for Windows (MSOpenTech) be a better solution?

Comment: In case of Redis there will be some cross process communication between your app and Redis even if they are on the same server, so it might slightly reduce performance of that operation. But you won't get GC issues in that approach as it will be stored in Redis

Comment: _"Might switching to xx or yy for Windows(MSOpenTech) be a better solution?"_ Depends.  Pro is that you can use them now. Cons - might not suit your needs.  Additionally, _Microsoft Windows Server AppFabric_ has a built-in object cache.  It can be local or distributed

Comment: I would recommend taking a different approach to this problem, you're fighting the system when it should be you who is conforming to it.  You state "It seems to think I use lots of data..", you do, you are caching 10gb+ worth of objects in memory.  Further stating "it begins to think its a good idea to scan the cache very often...", yes, sounds like GC is behaving exactly as it should.  Do you really need to cache 10GB+ worth of objects?  Whats the *real* cost of recreating one of the objects in the case of a cache miss?

Comment: Agree with Laurence, it sounds like you are describing a database with a key-value storage system like memcache, rather than an in-memory cache... Can you prioritise the frequently read items into a primary in-process cache and store the rest of the items in an out-of-process store like memcache?

Comment: "everything that goes in stays in" - that's a memory leak, not a cache.

Comment: There will be a ttl, but that was'nt the part i was interested in.
Your talking about memcached, which is a in-memory key-value storage and to me the term "cache" seems correct but it might be a database. If i have the memory is 10gb data in Memcached a bad idea? If i was to implement memcached in .Net, how would i do it? Object pooling?
I'm stuck with a existing MS-Sql database otherwise i believe a document database would fit my needs.

Comment: If anyone is interested i found some tips here.
http://blog.marcgravell.com/2011/10/assault-by-gc.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GC.TryStartNoGCRegion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.trystartnogcregion(v=vs.110).aspx) to strictly limit the times at which GC occurs.  Though in line with my previous comment, I believe this is not a good approach.

Have you considered examining how the cached objects are cleaning themselves up?  Perhaps when objects exceed the 4 hour ttl, cleaning them up takes too long?

Are the objects disposable?  Are they finalizable?  If yes to either one, whats the time cost of a Dispose or Finalize operation on an individual object?  If they are Finalizable, do they *need* to be?

Comment: The objects are not disposable or finalizable, and none of the objects inside them.
TTL is implemented with a sorted key,value storage with datetimes and when i access the store i check the object in one end if the datetime is more then ttl ago. if so i remove it from the list and check the next.
Might an immutabledictionary be bad to use here for my key/val storage? The dictionary will be replaced everytime a change is made.
I have this because the reading is 95% of the activity and i want a lock free solution.

Comment: ImmutableDictionary could be part of the problem, yes.  How are your objects moved from the old Dictionary to the new Dictionary?  Are they cloned, giving you 20gb worth objects, from which 10gb must be GC'ed?  As for locking, you could use a ReaderWriterLock instead of a standard lock, thus allowing simultaneous Read access, only requiring exclusive access when writing to the collection.

Comment: There are no standard locks, we use the built in system in ImmutableDictionary. So no cloning and no locks.
It builds a new dictionary containg the difference and repoints the cache to that. So readers never get locked. instead they might get some ms old data.
ImmutableCol = ImmutableCol.Add(myNewItem)
there are locks on the write though

Comment: @JohanLindberg I proposed the ReaderWriterLock because you stated that 95% of operations were Reads and that you wanted a lock free solution.  I assumed that to mean you were trying to avoid exclusive locks on reads.  The ReaderWriterLock allows simultaneous read locks, only requiring an exclusive lock during a write.

Comment: @JohanLindberg Also, ImmutableDictionary is Thread-Safe, so there is inherently some level of locking already present in your solution.

Comment: I thought the ImmutableDictionary was Thread-safe because its read-only? Not that it hold locks. You cannot alter an ImmutableDictionary. So the read performance should be better then using an readerwriterlock?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72246/discussion-between-johan-lindberg-and-laurence-adams).