# How to reduce garbage collection impact on a time dependent application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, garbage-collection, real-time

We have a **desktop** application that among several other things has to reset a watchdog timer every 500ms (after that the watchdog activates safety functions).

It normally works ok but on certain occasions the watchdog fires on some machines. It turns out that the garbage collector takes a bit more that 500ms doing its stuff and it blocks all the application threads.

Is there a way to reduce the time it spends on its job? As this is a continuous operation we cannot disable the garbage collection so we need a different solution here.

We haven't touched the GC settings so they are the default ones. Can the GC settings change how much it takes to run or are they just to control when it is activated?

Comment: There's a few different garbage collectors you can choose from, test which works the best for you. Or maybe you could have the watchdog as a separate application? Or increase the timeouts? :)

Comment: read this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#concurrent_garbage_collection

Comment: What type of application? What settings, if any, for the GC? You can probably solves this with the Server GC but we can't tell.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: added requested information.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: interesting link, thanks.

Comment: @Luaan: it cannot be a separate application. Is there a way of having it in a different AppDomain or a similar approach?

Comment: Perhaps moving the watchdog reset to a different high priority thread will also help

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia Nope. `AppDomain`s in one process still have just one GC. If you really need to squeeze the GC to under 500ms, experiment with the different GC settings. And find out why it takes so long in the first place.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Unlikely, if it's indeed caused by GC. The threads are frozen, so there's little point in changing their priority.

Comment: Providing such soft real-time guarantees is pretty questionable.  Did you take care of the basics?  Did you disable the paging file?  Ensured that no other process can ever run on that machine?  Ensured you always have enough RAM available?  Without having that done, the GC is the least of your problems.

Comment: You could look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28850042/net-garbagecollector-trouble-blocks-for-15-40-mins He did have even worse problems than you :)

Comment: @HansPassant: executing something every half second (something really fast and simple) shouldn't require such configurations unless I'm missing something. The CPU is at 1% and there is less than 2Gb used on a 4Gb machine when this happens. Do you need to disable the paging file to have a clock with second accuracy? (honest question)

Comment: Hmya, that's very fundamentally not the way it works.  The basic strategy the OS uses is "you lose what you don't use".  At 1%, you are not doing a lot of using.  So if you suddenly *do* need to use, by a machine request or a collection, then you do pay the price for swapping these pages back in.

Comment: **1.** The main problem here is that you have a time-critical requirement in a non-real-time environment. All sorts of things can happen on a Windows computer (or any other mainstream desktop OS) that could delay your code by 500ms. GC might be the most common scenario in .NET, but it's far from the only one. **2.** To address GC issues specifically, there are lots of techniques you can use. If it's _collection_ that's causing the problem, one thing you can do is minimize collection by maintaining a pool of objects yourself, instead of letting GC clean objects up.